# member class declaration issues

Tags: c++, class, declaration, member

I have having issues with class members and my declaration.  The first segment of code is my header file for "kdtilemapper.h"

```
#ifndef _KDTILEMAPPER_H
#define _KDTILEMAPPER_H

#include "tilemapper.h"
#include "kdtree.h"

class KDTileMapper : public TileMapper{
public:
    KDTileMapper( const SourceImage & si,const vector<TileImage> & tiles);
    ~KDTileMapper();
    KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs);
    KDTileMapper const & operator=(KDTileMapper const & rhs);
    int map_tiles(MosaicCanvas & mosaicOut) const;
private:
};
#endif /* _KDTILEMAPPER_H */
```

The below segment of code is the coding in question the **asterix** lines are where I am having errors in the compile for "tiles" not being declared and "tiles" not being in member class.

```
#include "kdtilemapper.h"
#include "kdtree.h"

KDTileMapper::KDTileMapper(const SourceImage & si, const vector<TileImage> & tiles):TileMapper(si,tiles)
{
    //TileMapper(si,tiles);
    //tileMapKDT=NULL;
}
KDTileMapper::~KDTileMapper(){


}
KDTileMapper::KDTileMapper(const KDTileMapper & rhs):TileMapper(rhs)
{
    source = rhs.source;
    **tiles = rhs.tiles;**  //tiles not declared and not member of const class KDTileMapper
}
KDTileMapper const & KDTileMapper::operator=(KDTileMapper const & rhs)
{
    source = rhs.source;
    **tiles= rhs.tiles;** //tiles not declared and not member of const class KDTileMapper
    return *this;
}
int KDTileMapper::map_tiles(MosaicCanvas & mosaicOut) const{
    int check1;
    TileImage tempTile1;
    TileImage tempTile2;
    int rows=source.get_rows();
    int columns=source.get_columns();
    **if(tiles.empty() || rows<0 || colums<0)** //tiles not declared, neither colums
    return -1;
    **KDTree<TileImage>* tileMapKDT= new KDTree<TileImage>(tiles[0].get_num_levels());**
    //tiles above is not declared
    for(int j=0;j< (int)tiles.size();j++)
    {
        if(!tiles[j].is_valid())
        return -1;
    }
    check1= tileMapKDT->create_tree(tiles);
    if(check1<0)
    return -1;

    mosaicOut=MosaicCanvas(rows,columns);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
        {
        tempTile1=TileImage(source.get_region_color(i,j));
        tempTile2=tileMapKDT->find_nearest_neighbor(tempTile1);
        mosaicOut.set_tile(i,j,tempTile2);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `tiles` member declared? Are we supposed to guess that it's in `TileMapper`?

Comment: The tiles variable is not declared in KDTileMapper. Is it declared in TileMapper? If it is, the problem may be in TileMapper, can you post the code from that class?

Comment: Your compiler seems to indicate that there's no declaration of anything named `tiles` in scope. I don't see anything like that either. Where is this declaration supposed to be? Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare `tiles` as private in `TileMapper` ? If that's the case you should declare it public or protected so the child class can access it.